# Para que serve e como funciona o ":eq(0)"?

Tags: jquery, seletores

Estava vendo um tutorial de *slider* para jQuery, e numa parte do código, no qual objetivo era voltar para a primeira imagem, o autor do código fez de um jeito que não conheço, e também não soube como pesquisar isso no Google:

```
$(".ativo").fadeOut().removeClass("ativo");
$("#slide img:eq(0)").fadeIn().addClass("ativo");
```

A parte de, `$("#slide img:eq(0)")` me deixou confuso, `img:eq(0)` ?

Como funciona isto do `:eq(0)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`:eq()` é um pseudo-selector para *index*.](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Ou seja se tiver *n* imagens descendentes de `#slide` então `eq(0)` vai escolher a primeira somente. Vale a pena lembrar que index começa em zero.

Exemplo:

```js
$("#slide div:eq(0)").css('color', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide">
    <div>numero 1</div> <!-- esta vai ficar azul -->
    <div>numero 2</div>
    <div>numero 3</div>
    <div>numero 4</div>
</div>
```

Neste caso poderia escrever-se assim também:

```
$("#slide img").eq(0) // exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hue60dd/1/
$("#slide img:first") // exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hue60dd/
```

Comment: Olha Sergio, espetacular resposta, respondeu perfeitamente, e ainda sugeriu outras formas, parabéns pelo trabalho que vem fazendo aqui, até mais!

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus obrigado!

Comment: Apenas reforçando a belíssima explicação do @Sergio, quando utilizamos `$('#slide img').eq(-1)`, retornamos o último elemento do grupo. Da mesma forma, podemos usar o "pseudo-selector" `:last`.